# Problem for backwards moving vehicle in hills

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

The vehicle running at Hill station.. Same time vehicle moves back ward direction in manual transmission system. So avoid the problem.. I think ratchet pinion mechanism suitable! or not?

Comment: Is it slipping? Have the brakes failed? What about the handbrake? And if you fit a ratchet/pinion system how would you get reverse gear?

Comment: Reverse gear engaged time  mechanism disconnected it's possible may be

Comment: How to avoid this problem?

Comment: is this an engineering question or a how-to-drive question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a system called a "hill holder" in cars which engages the parking brake on a hill while stopped. When the clutch is engaged to drive up the hill, the parking brake is slowly released by the mechanism. Manual transmission Subarus had this feature years ago.

Comment: Part of my driving test was to do that controlling handbrake, clutch and accelerator manually... not a problem.

Comment: Me too, but there are lots of people who re terrified by this. Studebaker offered a similar system in the 1950's.